# How to fix a break from ANTLR 4.2.2 to 4.3

Tags: antlr4

I'm guessing I am hitting the fix to #517 mentioned here:

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/571

but am not really sure. All I know is my xdot parser breaks if I move
from 4.2.2 to 4.3.

xdot has the idiom:   `N -<N characters go here>`. used pretty pervasively.
for example

`3 -ABC`
`4 -#@8&`

Which I have been implementing using (just a snippet here, and limiting the chars to digits):

```
integer returns [int v]
    :   
      lhs=integer DIGIT {$v = (10 * $lhs.v) + $DIGIT.int;}
    | DASH DIGIT {$v = - $DIGIT.int;}
    | DIGIT {$v = $DIGIT.int;}
    ;

bytes : integer SPACE DASH charSequence[$integer.v] ;

charElement : DIGIT ;

charSequence[int n]
  locals [int i = 1;]
 :  ( {$i<=$n}? charElement  {$i++;} )*  //match n chars
 ;
```

My guess is that the `$integer.v` reference in the bytes rule comes under the purvey
of the 571 break. I see that I am supposed to use the special symbol `$ctx` instead,
but alas I'm not seeing any examples of what I am supposed to do with it.

Comment: You're actually running into issue #672. I'd post a link but I'm on a phone and don't have it handy.

Comment: The link is: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/672 and it looks like I'll need to wait till 4.4.1? Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing a target code into a grammar you can use Visitors in ANTLR 4. Visitor visits the rules recursively and generates some actions which you can define.

```
integer
    :   
      lhs=integer DIGIT #lbl1
    | DASH DIGIT #lbl2
    | DIGIT #lbl3
    ;
public class MyVisitor<object> : BaseGrammarNameVisitor<object>
{
    public override object VisitLbl1 (Parser.Lbl1Context context)
    {
        return (10 * Int.ParseInt(Visit(context.integer()))) + Int.ParseInt(context.DIGIT.Text)
    }
    public override object VisitLbl2 (Parser.Lbl2Context context)
    {
        return - Int.ParseInt(context.DIGIT.Text)
    }
    public override object VisitLbl3 (Parser.Lbl3Context context)
    {
        return Int.ParseInt(context.DIGIT.Text)
    }
    //and so on...
}
```

I hope it will help.
Peta